# How can I access my own questions marked as duplicates?

Tags: discussion

I can't see in my profile my own questions previously marked by someone as duplicates. Are they accessible for a limited time? Even if they are not available for answering, I feel the asker should have access to own questions. It may be required for various reasons, for example to edit the question, to recall its content, to find links someone referred to as original answers. A question asked today, may come up again 2 years later, so I'd just look through my questions again, which is much faster than searching the web.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate questions won't be automatically deleted, and they're as accessible in your profile as any other question is.  The question could have been manually deleted by a moderator, yourself, or 3 users with sufficient privilege to vote to delete it, if they felt that the post didn't have merit as a signpost for other people (or for any other reason).

Comment: I just found that questions asked on Meta don't show up in SO profile. Is that typical for all SE family of sites? So a user must access own profile on each site to see own questions? Is it possible to access an aggregated profile instead with all questions collected from all SE sites?

Comment: @sambul35 you have a network profile: http://stackexchange.com/users/8755648/sambul35

Comment: Network profile is not aggregated. I can't see my questions asked on Meta in the Network Profile. May be I should! Is it possible to have it showing at least all SE subscriptions, including Meta, for easy own questions browsing?

Answer (score 2):

You can access your duplicate posts by using the search feature.

If you navigate to your profile page, in the top right hand corner the search bar will be prepopulted with your user id. Simply add "duplicate:1" to that and go and you will get your results.

These are your SO meta results:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6547333+duplicate%3A1

These are your SO main results:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6547333+duplicate%3A1

Comment: Thanks. I still feel, Network profile must be aggregated or provide easy links to all my profiles on SE family sites.

Comment: From what I can see, that is your only account.